# SAS code to add a row in the table if the expected value is missing

Tags: sas

I am naive to SAS. I managed other previous steps using PROC SQL. My table has 3 columns

```
 code     count    Fruit
  0         56      Apple
  6         58      orange
  7         676    orange
```

Add a row in the table for each product(Fruit) that does not have a code= 0 value then add count=0 as well in the table for eg additional row would be ...

```
 code      count    Fruit
  0          0      orange
```

started the code like this

```
Data table2;
SET table1;
IF code NE 0 then do;
```

Comment: Search PRELOADFMT or CLASSDATA to find out how to add the 0 values. Here's the thing to remember, computers are stupid. If it's not there, how does it know it should be there in the first place? You have to tell it somehow, and unfortunately that does mean you need to list it out somehow.

Comment: Are all of the possible values of FRUIT present in the data, but perhaps with other values of CODE other zero?  If not then is there another source to find all of the possible values of FRUIT?  Is zero the lowest (or highest) possible value of CODE?

Comment: Yes all the possible values of Fruit is there in the table.Zero is the lowest value of Code.

Comment: If you have all values of Fruit AND all values of Code in entries you can use the SPARSE option, but as I mentioned, if it's nowhere in your dataset then it won't work. Also, you'll  get all levels of code by all levels of Fruit and that may not be what you want.

Comment: Are the counts part of the source data? or something that you calculated?  If you are calculating the counts then perhaps the SPARSE option in PROC FREQ is all you need to get your zeros?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could sort the data by FRUIT and descending values of CODE and when the last record for a particular value of FRUIT does not have CODE=0 then add a record.

```
proc sort data=have out=want ;
   by fruit descending code ;
run;
data want ;
  set want ;
  by fruit ;
  output;
  if last.fruit and code ne 0 then do;
     code=0; count=0; output;
  end;
run;
```